# RJ45 Connection Test Fails for 4/6 Constantly

Tags: ethernet, cables, network

I am punching RJ45 keystones (configuration A) on each end of a Cat 5e cable. When I do a connection test, lights 4 and 6 doesn’t flash. I punched the keystones again, but no luck. Again lights 4 and 6 don’t flash. Numbers map to solid blue and orange respectively.

I started to think maybe I am missing something here. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Is the cable one you ran yourself? Or is it an existing cable ("came with the house")? If it is an existing cable, it may be spliced in the middle, particularly if it was previously used for phones rather than internet.

Comment: Odds are *excellent* that you have some *broken wires*, but they could be in your patch cables as suggested by Thomas's answer. Then again, they could be broken in the walls.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the standard tester with jacks, that you connect with short cable => **Replace the short cables**.

If you use a short cable long time, they may develop a fault that is non obvious (only appears in certain position), and is a real headache to figure out. Try new fresh patchcords with the tester and verify the punched cable again.
You can(should) also check the tester itself using a patch cord to verify it didn't develop a fault.

Comment: Check both patch cords (alone) with the tester. If the problem shows the same, try a new patch cord. If all three show the same fault, suspect the tester. If all three look good, suspect the wire in the wall. If at least one patch tests good, throw away any that don't.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Mind that the currently used patchcords may have an non-obvious fault (especially if crimped by user), so I recommend getting fresh ones.
Had issue like that once - the short self-crimped cords had discontinuity that shown only at certain angle (eg. hanging down the jack), and re-punched the cable 3 times before finding that out. They tested ok in the tester!

Answer (score 1):

Pull on each conductor, there's possibility that you damaged 4 and 6 when stripping the sheath.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to test the continuity one wire at a time. You will need a long piece of wire and a multimeter. This is not the fastest method but it is simple and removes most of the measurement errors. Connect the long wire to one of the Cat5 wires, connect the other end to your multimeter and then prob the same colored wire on the other end. I believe you will find that only 6 of the wires go through and two are open. If so make a 1/2 ethernet splitter. Not the best but saves pulling new cables. Connect one good pair to pins 1 & 2. Another good pair to pins 3 and 6. Colors do not matter but it would be nice to leave notes at both ends so your successor can figure out what is happening.Good luck and let us know how you did.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Gigabit Ethernet requires all four pairs to work. Having just two pairs limits you to 100 Mbps,which some might nowadays find insufficient.

Comment: 100MB is better than none if re-running the cable is a major pain, and sufficient unto the day for a great deal, even *nowadays.*

Comment: Are you quite certain that CAT 5 twisted pair cabling will work correctly when pairs are run separately? I thought that part of what made it work so well were the facts that A) the pairs were twisted and B) the bundle was intact.

Comment: @FreeMan Not 100% certain, but I am pretty sure that if (a) each *pair* is twisted appropriately and (b) the *pairs* are all very close to the same total length, that everything should work fine. AIUI, the twisting helps protect each pair from outside interference (other wires both in the cable and out), so separating the pairs from each other shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If you have two functional **pairs** you can run 100Mbit. That's not 4 random wires wired randomly. It's two sets of 2 wires that are twisted, connected one pair to 1&2, the other pair to 3&6. Heck, before Gigabit was a glimmer in the eye it was not uncommon to run two 100Mbit connections on the same Cat5 cable.